# Architecture Concerns

Tags: java, architecture, separation-of-concerns

My domain classes and persistance logic (Hibernate) are in one project called model. This jar is included within all of my apps.
***Packaged com.company.model & com.company.persistance***

Another Utils.jar - contains DateTime, String, Thread, etc general helper classes. This again is included within all of my apps.
***Packaged com.company.utils***

I have a CXF/Spring app that exposes services for manipulating my data. CRUD functionality, ALL other common functions. This is the 'way in' to my database for any app designed.
***Packaged com.company.services and running on Glassfish app server***

I have other apps that use the web services (Spring injected) to manipulate my data. Including a web app that will use YUI widgets and the XML/JSON from the web services for a nice smooth UI.

I understand its not really a question! I suppose Im looking for confirmation that this is how others are designing their software. If my architecture makes good, logical sense! Obviously there are security concerns - I will want some applications allowed to only access service x. I will address these later.

Comment: Please drop the ! -- it's confusing.  Your questions might be "Do others do this?"  or "Any problems?"  Or "Any suggested improvements?"  Please rewrite stating the actual thing you actually want to know.

Comment: Apologies. I suppose what I want to know is:

Do my design choices reflect what others are doing?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds good.

It depends also of the type of application you're developing and the specific requirements for that ( it has to be deployed every week, it has to be deployed in several locations etc )

But so far sounds good enough.

Looks like you can formulate a question from here in the future for some specific scenario.

Since this is not a question, mine is not really an answer. CW

Answer (score 0):

My only comment would be to put the persistence and Hibernate classes into a separate module; so that the `model` module can be purely beans/POJO/your domain classes.

Here's how I've organized a few multi-module projects before

- `project-data` - contains domain classes and DAOs (interfaces only)
- `project-services` - "Business logic" layer services, makes use of DAO interfaces.

  - Depends on `project-data`.
- `project-hibernate` - Hibernate implementation of DAO interfaces.

  - Depends on `project-data`.

Conceivably if I were to use some other sort of data-access method I would just create a separate module for that. Client apps could then choose which modules to be dependent on.

Answer (score 0):

Only suggestion I might have is that when you're creating service/models that you group them by subpackage name. ie

com.company.model.core
com.company.service.core

com.company.model.billing
com.company.service.billing

Also, be careful to ensure that no controller code (manipulating your UI) ends up in the services.